# Visual Studio 2008 - Images copied in explorer do not show up in Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have created a new folder in my project, aptly named 'images'. I have copy and pasted my images into the folder via explorer, but how do I get them to show up in studio, so when I do img tags or whatever I get the src... dropdown and I can navigate to the image that I want?

Ok, I have followed the advice and now have the folder and all the images within it visible to my project.  I'm actually following a tutorial about creating a login page etc for a web project.  It all works and now I am working on layout.  I have added an image tag to my login page, as simple as , the src is correct, the image is definitely there, but the image will not show up on the page, why??

I must be suffering from 'lack of brains friday' syndrome because this has got me stumped!

It works on the other pages in the project, but not the Login.aspx page!

Thanks.

Comment: You should do a new question for a separate topic. In your new question, make sure to post code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using a web application project you have to manually add them to the project. Right click "images" and Add > Existing Item and choose your new images.

Answer (score 3):

The files are probably not included in your project...

Menu: Project -> Show all files...

Then select them in the solution explorer, right click and include them in the project. You can turn off "Show all files" after that.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of project is it? It could be that you need to add the files to the project explicitly. In the solution explorer, click the button "Show all files", and the files should show up. Select the newly added files, right-click and select "Include in project".

Answer (score 1):

Face the same issue on Visual Studio 2017 , and fix the issue using below button that located on Solution explorer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hit the Refresh button at the top of the solution explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Or just right-click folder and 'Refresh'.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, in Visual Studio 2010 at the top of the Solution Explorer window there is a button called "Show All Files". Clicking this will show the files that you have copied into the directory. Then you need to right click on each file and choose "Include in Project".